# CSS - Margin-top won't work on one selector, but does in compatability mode

Tags: html, css, margin

I am making a website and have split the site into the usual header, maincontainer and footer divs. The maincontainer contains 3 extra divs and all 3 divs (section 1,2,3) have a margin-top: 5px command associated to them. The first 2 divs (section 1 and 2) work perfectly, but the 3rd div (section 3) doesn't work at all. It just stays glued beneath section 2. However, if I go to IE compatibility mode, the 3rd div will drop down by the 5px specified in the CSS.

Code below.
CSS:

```
#middlecontainer {
width: 960px;
height: auto;
}

.section1, .section2, .section3{
width: 960px;
margin-top: 5px !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="middlecontainer">
<div class="section1">
<div class="promo1">
<h1>Celebrate the real flavour of Indian cuisine at Mela.</h1>
<p>&nbs</p>
<p>&nbsp</p>
</div>
<div class="promo2">
<img src="images/home-1.jpg" alt="Mela West End, London" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="section2">
<div class="promo3">
<img src="images/mela-limitless.gif" alt="Up to 50% off Mela Limitless" />
</div>
<div class="promo4">
<img src="images/gift-vouchers.gif" alt="Mela's Gift Vouchers" />
</div>
<div class="promo5">
<img src="images/food-1.jpg" alt="Mela Curries" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="section3">
<div class="promo6">
<img src="images/visit-redhill.gif" alt="Visit Mela Redhill in Surrey" />
</div>
<div class="promo7">
<img src="images/recipe-of-the-month.jpg" alt="Mela's Recipe of the Month" />
</div>
<div class="promo8">
<img src="images/cookery-class.gif" alt="Did you buy a cookery class" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

If needed I can provide the CSS code for the .promo divs, but as they are child elements I didn't think that would effect the parent div.

Keith

EDIT: 
Here is the code put into jsFiddle, it seems to work fine in here though so I am completely stumped as to why it won't work in my browser. http://jsfiddle.net/8xpxH/4/

Comment: it is working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8xpxH/1/). do you have a [doctype](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) specified? what browsers have you tested in?

Comment: @CarrieKendall I have XHTML 1.0 Transitional specified on the page. It doesn't work on any browser I test in (Safari 5.1.7, Firefox 20.0.1, Chrome 26 and IE 10) but does work in IE 10 Compatability. It's like the .section3 is sticking to the bottom of .section2

Comment: show all of your css.

Comment: Do you have defined some negative margins - most likely on `promo5`?

Comment: @CarrieKendall added link to all code put in jsFiddle. Hope this helps! Seems to work fine in there but my browsers it still acts is if .section3 isn't picking up the margin-top:5px. http://jsfiddle.net/8xpxH/4/

Comment: Do you have a LIVE link of this site so I can take a look with dev tools?

Comment: @Christoph no I don't have any negative margins, I reset them all at the beginning of the CSS when I started building, that's about it.

Comment: @Michael http://www.melarestaurant.co.uk/newsite/shaftesbury/

Comment: @Keith Same problem on live site.  Let me take a look.  Un momento ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you float your promo-elements, the parent elements (`.sectionX`) have height 0. This messes up your margins.

You need to clear the floats. Easiest way to to this is to set `overflow:auto` and everything is fine. (`auto` might make (unnecessary) scrollbars appear which can be problematic, so if you are sure, your stuff fits perfectly and there will be no overflow issues take `hidden` instead.)

```
.section1, .section2, .section3{
   width: 960px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Just done this and whilst I thankfully have my +5 margin from .section2 and .section3, the entire site has just gone mad on me. http://www.melarestaurant.co.uk/newsite/shaftesbury/ will that be to do with my widths?

Comment: @Keith what exactly do you mean with gone mad? It looks fine for me (Chrome).

Comment: in IE the promo divs in .section2 and .section3 have gone out of sync (2 on the first row, 1 on the second row, all should be on row 1) and in Firefox, same issue but .section1 (1st div on row 1, 2nd div on row 2)

Comment: Sounds like a the combination of your widths and left-right margins have calculated to be greater than 100%, and your last divs are moving to a new line because theres not enough space.

Comment: Yes, I see the same in Chrome @Keith Changing the widths of your center divs to 320px fixed it for me.

Comment: @Keith take `overflow:hidden` instead. I fixed the answer.

Comment: @Christoph wicked man! works all fine for me now :) So why did the overflow: auto send it crazy and the overflow: hidden fixed it? just so I know for next time :)

Comment: @christoph fantastic, thank you so much for the answer and to everyone else :-)